# pycurl CONNECT_TIME on windows

Tags: python, networking, pycurl

I am using windows with pycurl, I am having an issue with timings when returning the CONNECT_TIME where by timings are not accurate.

Is there a way to make the connect_time in windows more accurate when using pycurl.

At the moment I am using the following.

```
stats['connection_time'] = self.getinfo(CONNECT_TIME)
```

If I were to use the time.clock() methods around the code then this will not return the connection time but rather the total_time which is a deterrent metric.

Comment: looking at [the curl source](https://github.com/bagder/curl/blob/master/lib/timeval.c) it should provide time differences with enough precision (don't know about accuracy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Completely forgot about this question but thought I would answer it for others. It appears as though pycurl suffers from granularity issues similar to the one you would get when using time.time on windows.

Instead I have had to edit my code and manually time the length of time taken to complete tasks.

Comment: you could use `timeit.default_timer()` for cross-platform code

Comment: That is true it is an option